# JsonSchema - Only allow one item in an array field if another array field is defined

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following json and would like to only allow "leads" to contain only a single "id" item if there is a "tokens" array present (with at least one item).

JSON

```
{
"input": {
    "leads": [
        {
            "id": 795333333760
        }
    ],
    "tokens": [
      {
        "name": "tem_x",
        "value": "Renew_all"
      },
      { 
        "duration": "90",
        "eligibility": "eligible"
      }
    ]
}
```

I have the following schema, that indicates "tokens" can have more than one item if present and that "leads" is required.

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "input": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "leads": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "id"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "tokens": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1
      
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "leads",
    ]
  }
},
"required": [
  "input"
]
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that only one item in "leads" can be allowed if "tokens" is present (as it is not defined as a required field). If "tokens" is not defined, then I would like to allow the "leads" array to have more than one item.

I played around with if-then but wasn't able to get it working right. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This would be easier if you're able to upgrade to at least JSON Schema draft-07. If you can, I will provide another answer. Please let me know.

Comment: @Relequestual, I'll be doing the validation using the python jsonschema library which supports draft-07 so that should not be a problem. Thank you for assisting.

Comment: Great! As a hint before I'm able to spend time on this, the value of `if` and `then` are themselves schemas. If you want the `then` schema to be applied, the `if` schema has to pass validation.

Comment: Jasons answer is good =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of thing the `dependencies` keyword is for. It can be done with `if`/`then` or implication as well, but `dependencies` removes all the extra boilerplate needed for those patterns. The following says, if the "tokens" property is defined, then the "leads" property must have at most 1 item. This would go inside your "input" schema.

```
"dependencies": {
  "tokens": {
    "properties": {
      "leads": { "maxItems": 1 }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**: `dependencies` works in draft-04 thru draft-07. In draft 2019-09 and up, you can use `dependentSchemas` instead.

Comment: Can you add `$schema` please? =]

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. I was playing with  'dependencies' previously but was not specifying it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

try to use like this:

```
    {
      "properties": {
        "tokens": {},
        "leads": {}
      },
      "anyOf": [{
        "required" : ["tokens"]
      }, {
        "required" : ["leads"]
      }]
    }

so schema looks like this:

"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "input": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "leads": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "id"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "tokens": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1
      
      }
    },
    "anyOf": [{
    "required" : ["tokens"]
  }, {
    "required" : ["leads"]
  }]
  }
},
"required": [
  "input"
]
}
```

Comment: With the above schema, "leads" is allowed more than one item if "tokens" is defined. I would like "leads" to only have a single item in that case.